# GCM pushEvent issue

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, service-worker, web-push, push-api

I have sent push notification to service-worker using GCM api. But in my service-worker has no attribute data. Hence, I am getting event.data as undefined.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {  
   console.log('Received a push message', event);
   console.log('testing');

var data = event.data;
var title = data.title;
var body = data.body;
var icon = '/images/image.png';  
var tag = 'simple-push-demo-notification-tag';

event.waitUntil(function() {
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {  
        body: body,  
        icon: icon,  
        tag: tag  
     })
   });
 });
```

In below code, I call GCM api.

```
uri = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send'
payload = json.dumps({
             'registration_ids': [
                User.objects.filter(id=user_id)[0].push_key     
                 ], 
              'data': json.dumps({'title':'New notification','message': 'new message'}) 
           })
headers = {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Authorization': 'key=<Project key>'
         } 
 requests.post(uri, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you've taken parts of the code, not all of it, and as a result, it's not working.

If you at the simple push demo repo, there is a function showNotification.

[Here for Ref](https://github.com/gauntface/simple-push-demo/blob/master/app/service-worker.js#L9)

```
function showNotification(title, body, icon, data) {
  console.log('showNotification');
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: body,
    icon: icon ? icon : '/images/touch/chrome-touch-icon-192x192.png',
    tag: 'simple-push-demo-notification',
    data: data
  };
  return self.registration.showNotification(title, notificationOptions);
}
```

There is where data is defined.

The data passed into this isn't from the event (or have anything to do with the event object).

To get your code running, just simplify it:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {  
  console.log('Received a push message', event);
  console.log('testing');

  var title = 'My Title';
  var body = 'My notification body';
  var icon = '/images/image.png';  
  var tag = 'simple-push-demo-notification-tag';

  event.waitUntil(function() {
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {  
      body: body,  
      icon: icon,  
      tag: tag  
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Matt for clarification. By the way, I got an idea that data is stored in event from your article in blog. [link] (https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/12/15/push-notifications-service-worker). As per my understanding, GCM api triggers service-worker, which in turn send push notification. In the link you have mentioned (weather data example), How do I give parameter to api (for e.g. city name)? Will it be given through GCM api? If yes, then how do I get that parameter in service worker (though event.data?)